# Multiple integration for a function dependent on 2+ variables

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, integration, physical-chemistry

I will be considering a common thermo relationship:

$$
dG\;=\;dH\;-T\;dS$$
Would this imply that $$G(H,T,S)\;=\;\int_{H1}^{H2}\int_{T1}^{T2}\int_{S1}^{S2}(dH-TdS)\;\;?$$ Would this be possible if we were given bounded conditions for each variable of $G$ ?

I am a young undergrad, please be kind for my lack of understanding.

Comment: How much calculus have you learned?

Comment: No, Joel. The right hand side of the second equality you have written doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

To get a better grasp I recommend some basics of differential geometry, in particular differential forms.

$dG = dH - T dS$ tells us that
\begin{equation}
\left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial H}\right)_S = 1 \quad \text{and} \quad \left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial S}\right)_H = -T.
\end{equation}

The process to get $G$ from that is not strictly integration - you have to find the "potential" or "primitive" form of $dG$. It means that you want to find the function that satisfies the conditions above.

One procedure would be to write:
\begin{align}
&G(H,S) = \int_{H_0}^H dH' \cdot \left.\left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial H}\right)_S\right|_{(H',S)} = \int_{H_0}^H dH' \cdot 1  = H-H_0 + f(S) \\
&G(H,S) = \int_{S_0}^S dS' \cdot \left.\left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial S}\right)_H\right|_{(H,S')} = \int_{S_0}^S dS' \cdot \left(-T(H,S)\right)  + g(H).
\end{align}
Where $g$ and $h$ are some functions that have to be determined such that the two expressions for $G(H,S)$ coincide and by the boundary condition $G_0 = G(H_0, S_0)$.

Note, that we couldn't solve this problem because we lack the expression for $T(H,S)$.

Comment: thank you so very much! makes a lot more sense. apologies for the dumb question, you understood what I was asking.